# Delete links in same modules Doors

Tags: ibm-doors, baseline

i would like to ask if there is a way to delete all the out links from one baseline to another baseline in the same module. I used link-> delete links - and chosen files but it didn't work for the same modules

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Baselines are frozen and cannot be changed. If the Link starts in a baseline, you cannot delete it. You can only delete a link that starts in a current version and ends either in a current version of the same or another module or in a baseline.